# Play MP3 file from app

Tags: c#, media

I've found some code snips online but issue is they use file locations hosted local on system, I would like to play a MP3 or wav from my app and build the mp3 file into the app rather then them needing it as well as the .exe. Any idea of how to do such a thing?

Comment: WPF or WinForms, what kind of app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed your mp3 or wav as resource:

1. Right click your project in solution explorer.
2. Select Add / Existing Item... from the menu Select and add your file.
3. Select a newly added file in the  solution explorer, right click on it
4. Choose Properties from right-click menu
5. Change its Build Action property to Embedded Resource

Play it using the following code:

```
WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(). GetManifestResourceStream("yourfile.mp3");
string temppath = Path.GetTempPath() + "\\temp.mp3";
using (Stream output = new FileStream (temppath, FileMode.Create))
{
   byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
   int read;

        while ( (read= stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
}
wmp.URL = temppath;
wmp.controls.play();
```

Don't forget to delete the temporary file when you are done with it.